# Python Bottle website visible over network?

Tags: python, web, network-programming, bottle

Is there a way to make my website accessible over the network that I'm connected to?

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: Try `run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)`. Deatails are here: http://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 2):

as [@fukanchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655436/fukanchik) explained in comments, you have to use `host='0.0.0.0'` in the run command to make bottle listen to all available ips in your system.

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

For more information you can check this question:[whats the difference between ip address 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1)